# Adding information to JWT token body using django rest framework jwt

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, pyjwt

Im using django rest framework and the djangorestframework-jwt package to creat JWT tokens for authorization.

On the frontend I can decode the token and get the username, email and user_id. However I would like to retrieve some extra information. For example it would be very convenient if I could get `kind` which is a field on our authorization model (user model).

I can ofcourse make a separate request to get the user info via a regular APIView. But I'm wondering if it's possible to add some extra params in the JWT body?

Comment: yes you can edit utils.py inside djangorestframework-jwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in this [github issue](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/307), I did this by subclassinng the `ObtainJSONWebToken` class from DRF-JWT:

```
from rest_framework_jwt import views as jwt_views
from .serializers import UserSerializer 

class UserLoginViewJWT(jwt_views.ObtainJSONWebToken):
    user_serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response =  super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=request.data[get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD])
            serialized_user = self.user_serializer_class(user)
            response.data.update(serialized_user.data)
        return response
```

**Note:** the code above is probably missing some imports

A reply from @jpadilla also specified that

> You can also do this with the JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER setting.
>   http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#jwt_response_payload_handler

Answer (score 10):

Using the [djangorestframework_simplejwt](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) library

1. Specify in settings.py the USER_ID_FIELD and ALGORITHM

   ```
   SIMPLE_JWT = {
       'USER_ID_FIELD': 'user_id',
       'ALGORITHM': 'HS512',
   }
   ```

Let's say you want to add fields to the body of TokenObtainPairView which has the following body

[image: Token Obtain Pair body]

```
{
    "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTU5MDk5ODAwMSwianRpIjoiMjZhZThhYTU4YTJiNDU3M2JlMDgxNTMzMzU1ODg4ZmUiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMX0.-jUCnfpTF-RsqHnuoEgctPpHf1SfYNcYaPs8oo01RvrQBMcyhms5PfWipfYkaR0FlPHSTKncNeMxomwd4k7nyg",
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkwOTExOTAxLCJqdGkiOiI5NjZkOTFhNzEzNjg0NjMyOGUzYWU3NThiNzNiZmYxMyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjExfQ.LiHrekmlHrM7_5187ghpIaA6mKcPCjDz4MDKPXHc4QAKVGvcJCJpCjrODCB4-pZn4Kuai5ht3YjWwYSirxpsXw"
}
```

2. Add in your urls.py

   ```
   path('api/token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain'),
   ```
3. Create the MyTokenObtainPairView

   ```
   class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
       serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer`
   ```
4. Create the MyTokenObtainPairSerializer

   ```
   class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
       def validate(self, attrs):
           data = super().validate(attrs)
           refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
           data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
           data.pop('refresh', None) # remove refresh from the payload
           data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

           # Add extra responses here
           data['user'] = self.user.username
           data['kind'] = self.user.kind
           data['date'] = datetime.date.today()
           return data
   ```

This way when you post to /api/token/ you'll get in the body something like this

```
{
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkwOTEwNTc0LCJqdGkiOiIwM2Q5MzA1NTZmNzk0NmFjODU1MzJlNTYzNjUwZDY0MCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjExfQ.H0huO84qtzdbo4OkKhsW_vtNTGwInG67gum6f138h1y66EiyZ1BvxaxbfEE2oPG4pB0XjiWQrXc5PlR9C6UvfQ",
    "user": "tiago",
    "kind": "whatever_this_has"
    "date": "2020-05-31"
}
```

Comment: Is this mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: @KrishnadasPC not that I know of

Comment: Martin How did you find this then? the code works for me but couldn't find this anywhere else.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC it came in a moment I wanted to add to both body and claims. See also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62066402/5675325) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62113587/5675325).