# DRF SimpleJWT remove password and add date field

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I created a custom user model extending from AbstractBaseUser where the only data I'm getting from the user is a userID, user (the username field) and date (required and in the format *dd-mm-yyyy*) and the creation of the user works fine as you can see from the DB in the next image

[image: user table in HeidiSQL]

Used `password = None` and `last_login = None` to refer i didn't want password and last_login tables.

Then, created a view where only authenticated users can access.

To handle the authentication, used [simpleJWT](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt). In urls.py

```
# JWT Token
path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain'),
# Get a new token before the old expires.
path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view, name='token_refresh'),
```

And by going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/ , this is what I see (which works as expected)

[image: DRF simple JWT]

I've tested previously with User and Password in a different project with user model that included that data (User and Password) and worked fine. Now, here, if I try Posting with an existing user but with no password, I get a warning and not being able to Post

> This field may not be blank.

[image: simpleJWT without password]

If i add anything other than a blank space, the following error appears

> TypeError at /api/token/
>   object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

[image: not working simplejwt]

How can I remove the Password field? Also, how could I add a Date field too?

Comment: What is the point of obtaining a user token without password?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu It's for a specific scenario and that is needed.

Comment: idk about your requirement, but, what if I know your *"username"*?

Comment: I understand that @ArakkalAbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same problem and somehow I have manage to solve this problem.

Here is the solution,

1. Override the `TokenObtainPairSerializer` class `__init__` method like below,
2. Use `del password` so It wont ask you the password and add whatever fields you want.

`class CustomSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[self.username_field] = serializers.CharField()
        del self.fields['password']
        self.fields['last_login'] = serializers.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)`

This works really well.

Here is the reference - [How to skip or remove password field in simplejwt token authentication in django rest framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475301/how-to-skip-or-remove-password-field-in-simplejwt-token-authentication-in-django)?

Let me know if anyone have better solution of this.