# Adding claims to DRF simple JWT payload

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Using [djangorestframework_simplejwt](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) library, when POST to a custom view

```
#urls.py
path('api/token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain'),

#views.py
class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

I'm able to get a the following access token

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkwOTEwNjg0LCJqdGkiOiI3M2MxYmZkOWNmMGY0ZjI3OTY4MGY0ZjhlYjA1NDQ5NyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjExfQ.5vs0LmNGseU6rtq3vuQyApupxhQM3FBAoKAq8MUukIBOOYfDAV9guuCVEYDoGgK6rdPSIq2mvcSxkILG8OH5LQ
```

By going to https://jwt.io/ I can see the payload is currently

```
{
  "token_type": "access",
  "exp": 1590910684,
  "jti": "73c1bfd9cf0f4f279680f4f8eb054497",
  "user_id": 11
}
```

[image: JWT]

So, we can see that the second part of the token is the payload - containing the claims.

I've explored [how to add more information to the Response body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62113178/5675325) and now would like to know how to customize the Payload data by adding [iat claim](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.6), username and today's date.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you already created a subclass for the desired view (MyTokenObtainPairView) and a subclass for its corresponding serializer (MyTokenObtainPairSerializer), add the following to the serializer

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    ...

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['iat'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        token['user'] = user.username
        token['date'] = str(datetime.date.today())

        return token
```

Then, when you POST to that same location, you'll get an access token like this

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkwOTE0MTk4LCJqdGkiOiJhZDZmNzZhZjFmOGU0ZWJlOGI2Y2Y5YjQ4MGQzZjY2MiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjExLCJpYXQiOjE1OTA5MTc0OTgsInVzZXIiOiJ0aWFnbyIsImRhdGUiOiIyMDIwLTA1LTMxIn0.-5U9P-WWmhlOenzCvc6b7_71Tz17LyNxe_DOMwwqH4RqrNsilVukEcZWFRGupLHRZjIvPya2QJGpiju9ujzQuw
```

Using JWT you can see the Payload changing accordingly

[image: Custom Payload simpleJWT Django]

```
{
  "token_type": "access",
  "exp": 1590914198,
  "jti": "ad6f76af1f8e4ebe8b6cf9b480d3f662",
  "user_id": 11,
  "iat": 1590917498,
  "user": "tiago",
  "date": "2020-05-31"
}
```

Comment: I believe the correct source for the token's issuance timestamp is `token.current_time` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`. `token.current_time` is calculated when a `Token` instance is created and then used to derive other data such as the expiry. Using `datetime.now()` later on might provide a different timestamp than the one that was originally calculated.

Comment: @DavidM. you might be right, yes. The goal here was simply to add new claims, its value was irrelavant.

Comment: @Tiago, if I want to send a image along with the refresh and acces token ? Do you maybe have a idea how to do that

Comment: Is there a way to add IP Address to the payload??

Comment: @FreddCha yes, you can add pretty much anything you want

Answer (score 5):

**In your views.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from decouple import config
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
import jwt




@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def get_tokens_for_user(request):

    username = request.POST.get("username")
    password = request.POST.get("password")

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password);

    if user is not None:

        refreshToken = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        accessToken = refreshToken.access_token

        decodeJTW = jwt.decode(str(accessToken), config('SECRET_KEY'), algorithms=["HS256"]);

        # add payload here!!
        decodeJTW['iat'] = '1590917498'
        decodeJTW['user'] = 'tiago'
        decodeJTW['date'] = '2020-05-31'

        #encode
        encoded = jwt.encode(decodeJTW, config('SECRET_KEY'), algorithm="HS256")
    
        return Response({
            'status': True,
            'refresh': str(refreshToken),
            'access': str(encoded),
        })

    else:
        return Response({
            'status': False
        })
        # No backend authenticated the credentials
```

**In your urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import get_tokens_for_user

urlpatterns = [

        path('login/', get_tokens_for_user, name="login"),
]
```

**In your settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta
from decouple import config

...
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    # Rest
    'rest_framework',
...
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]

}

# JWT
# https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'SIGNING_KEY': config('SECRET_KEY'),
    'VERIFYING_KEY': config('SECRET_KEY'),
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
}
```

In your root directory add
.env

```
SECRET_KEY = 'ep@4ojr4m!h73y2j(stackoverflow)kra1*@tq$5el626wf@&p60)7u!6552+-'
```

**Runtime values**

```
 decodeJTW =   {
    'token_type': 'access',
    'exp': 1612651527,
    'jti': '7f415b28610348468ce74ec0f480fad1',
    'user_id': 2,
    'iat': '1590917498',
    'user': 'tiago',
    'date': '2020-05-31'
}

encode = {
   "status":true,
    "refresh":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYxMjczNDU0NywianRpIjoiMDQ0MDI3ZTQzMTc2NDFiNDhhOGI2MjU4MjE4ZGZjNDkiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyfQ.Qf0YfJLAmdYuavDHVng7Bwjmka551G6c1Gi4e-UdRuc",
"access":"b'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjEyNjUxNzQ3LCJqdGkiOiI2OWEzNjYwYjYxMTk0MzVjYjljZTA0OGQ3MmE1ODk1YSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjIsImlhdCI6IjE1OTA5MTc0OTgiLCJ1c2VyIjoidGlhZ28iLCJkYXRlIjoiMjAyMC0wNS0zMSJ9.XUMvhL13zDZdbjYYPkYnwlZoHN6U7Zc3xUzXsKoVj2I'"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I came here looking for a solution to add the token expiration to the response while working with [dj-rest-auth](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) and  djangorestframework_simplejwt I found a solution in the [code](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/blob/485a0b0da1537737a19e204bacf8db079598627e/dj_rest_auth/views.py#L56) (apparently undocumented?):

There is a setting called JWT_AUTH_RETURN_EXPIRATION which, if set to True, adds the expiration to the response like so:

```
{
    "access_token": "ACCESS_TOKEN_STRING",
    "refresh_token": "REFRESH_TOKEN_STRING",
    "user": {
        "pk": PK,
        "email": "USER_EMAIL"
    },
    "access_token_expiration": "2021-02-10T10:40:46.883715Z",
    "refresh_token_expiration": "2021-02-11T10:35:46.883728Z"
}
```

and same for refresh:

```
{
    "access": "ACCESS_TOKEN_STRING",
    "access_token_expiration": "2021-02-10T10:47:57.325545Z"
}
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for, It is to add clai,s to JWT Token